Exterior Door is not Closing
My wife and I just purchased a home that was built in the 1960's. The area consists of clay. We have a basement, and there are 2 teleposts centered in the basement.
We have been living here for a couple of months now. Just last week, we noticed our front exterior door was becoming very difficult to open and close. The top handle side of the door was catching the jamb. I tried putting 3" screws in the top hinge, and that didn't work. I removed the pin from the top hinge and in order to close the door, there needed to be a pretty big adjustment (maybe 1/2"?). I put some shims between the hinge and the door (on the door side), and that fixed it; however just this week, we are now back to not being able to use that door. A couple of the upstairs interior doors are a little sticky, more so compared to when we bought the house as well, but none are like the front exterior door. This door is not a wood door, maybe aluminum or composite. The exterior door located at the rear of the house works great, as do most other doors (albeit we have many pocket doors). I'm sure there has been shifting over the years, the basement does not have an even floor, but I would think it is likely many basement don't.
My questions are:

What is causing this? I would imagine if the door was sagging, wouldn't the 3" at the top hinge have likely fixed this? Is there something else I can try in case it is a sagging issue?

Is this caused by a shifting house, and, if so, is this a serious issue? What would be the next-steps? I don't like to subscribe to the doomsday mentality, so objective rational thinking is paramount IMO.

If this is caused by a shifting house, is this common and should I make adjustments to the teleposts?


Now part 3 brings up an entirely new set of questions (sorry about the length here folks, I'm almost done). The 2 teleposts run parallel to the exterior door. I have never made adjustments to teleposts, so I apologize if these questions are silly, but here they are:

How do you know what direction to adjust the teleposts? I would think purchasing a laser level would be required, and then checking the floor upstairs, but what is your baseline? How can you determine if both should go up, both should go down, one to go up or down?

If the door issue is likely being caused by a shifting house, and adjustments to the teleposts are a common thing homeowners should do, I understand adjustments should be made once a month, and only by small increments. If this is something I should be doing routinely, is there a baseline system I should be using to make sure I am adjusting everything correctly? I've heard of someone installing a light system which is activated depending on which way the support beam moves, but I don't know I want to get this techy :)


Thanks everyone. I'm hoping to obtain some reassurance that my house isn't falling apart, and that this is something I can fix. If it is out of my hands and I should call someone, I am OK going this route as well; but I want to come with the information of who I need to call, what I can expect and have a plan prior to going down this road (like I do with any major job I am looking to tackle). I spent a lot of time with this door, and our relationship has been frustrating to say the least, so it's time I find myself here for mediation counselling so help solve our issues.

I have no idea what a telepost is, but please ask one question per post. See [ask] and take the [tour]. Remove irrelevant commentary about your feelings, relationships, and future plans. Just facts, please. Photos of your door (both up close and in context) are fairly important to good answers here.

A telepost is a vertical metal pole that supports the wood support beams holding up the house. They can be adjusted up and down. I apologize for the multiple questions, but I am really asking one question here: based on the background information, which of these is likely causing the door to not fit into the jamb properly.

HI Mathew, photos would help a lot.  And as mentioned above, its too verbose.  Ask a simple question without options.  What if its an option you dont have in the list?

Fair enough. Given the complexity of the situation, I'm not sure the internet is where your solution lies. I have a lot of construction experience but I'm not comfortable telling you how or whether to crank on posts in your basement. You should have someone local take a look. (FYI, you never need a laser level. A water or spirit level can give you points at which to set strings for reference.)

Your location might be important.  A 60s house is usually finish settling by now.   A loose top hinge usually lowers the latch side.
